Descriptor in DataClass
Here is descriptor class:
#descriptor
class Validator:
    def __set_name__(self,owner,name):
        self.private_name = '_' + name
    def __set__(self,obj,value):
        self.validate(value)
        setattr(obj, self.private_name, value)
    def __get__(self,obj,objtype = None):
        return getattr(obj,self.private_name)
        
    @abstractmethod
    def validate(self,value):
        pass`


Here is the user Validator class:
class UserValidator(Validator):
    def validate(self,value):
        if(len(value)<=2):
            raise ValueError("username length must be greater than 2")

Here is dataclass
@dataclass   
class LoginBody:
    user:str = UserValidator()

And i read in documentation of descriptors that "Descriptors only work when used as class variables. When put in instances, they have no effect."
I just want to know what happening in LoginBody class, is descriptor used as instance variable or class variable?
b = LoginBody('user')
print(b.user)

Here output is 'user'
But how i am getting above output

Try this code:

I added print statements in __set__() and __get__() methods,
so you can see what's happening.

from abc import abstractmethod
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


# descriptor
class Validator:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.private_name = '_' + name

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        print(f'setting {obj.__class__.__qualname__}().{self.private_name} to `{value}`')
        if value is self:
            # no value is provided for __init__()
            # we could use a default, but here we raise same error, as if attribute was defined like:
            #  user: str
            raise TypeError(f"{obj.__class__.__qualname__}.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: '{self.private_name[1:]}'")

        self.validate(value)
        setattr(obj, self.private_name, value)

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        print(f'getting {obj} {objtype}')
        return getattr(obj, self.private_name)

    @abstractmethod
    def validate(self, value):
        pass


class UserValidator(Validator):

    def validate(self, value):
        if len(value) <= 2:
            raise ValueError(f"{value}: username length must be greater than 2")


@dataclass
class LoginBody:
    # remove `repr=False` if you need field to show up when you do `print(c)`
    user: str = field(default=UserValidator(), repr=False)

    # compare to below -- it has 2 more __get__() method calls!
    # user: str = UserValidator()


c = LoginBody('abc')
print(f'{c.user=}')

# raises:
#   ValueError: ab: username length must be greater than 2
c = LoginBody('ab')
print(c.user)

Also, in Validator.__set__(), the following logic:
if value is self:
    # no value is provided for __init__()
    # we could use a default, but here we raise same error, as if attribute was defined like:
    #  user: str
    raise TypeError(f"{obj.__class__.__qualname__}.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: '{self.private_name[1:]}'")

Fixes it so the below doesn't work anymore:
c = LoginBody()


Class attribute. There is never an instance attribute named user, only the class attribute. There is an associated field, however, generated from the annotated assignment, which is used to generate an __init__ method that looks roughly like
def __init__(self, user):
    self.user = user

but that assignment to self.user triggers the descriptor's __set__ method and creates the instance attribute _user, which b.user subsequently reads via the __get__ method.
>>> dataclasses.fields(LoginBody)[0]
Field(name='user',type=<class 'str'>,default=<dataclasses._MISSING_TYPE object at 0x10918de20>,default_factory=<dataclasses._MISSING_TYPE object at 0x10918de20>,init=True,repr=True,hash=None,compare=True,metadata=mappingproxy({}),kw_only=False,_field_type=_FIELD)
>>> LoginBody.__dict__['user']
<__main__.UserValidator object at 0x10917f710>

